# Prove that $D'=D$ without using the fact that $xy=yx$ (Sorry best i got to describe the question)

Tags: geometry

[image]Given collinear points $O,A,B$ and $C$ such that $|OA|=1, |OB|=x, |OC|=y$, construct another line through $O$ and points $A',B',C'$ such that $|OA'|=1, |OB'|=x, |OC'|=y$. Construct the line through $C'$ parallel to $A'B$ and let $D$ be the intersection of this line with $OA$.

(a) Show that $|OD|=xy$

This part is relatively simple using thales theorem.

(b) Let $D'$ be the intersection of $OA$ with the line through $B'$ parallel to $A'C$. Then the previous part of the question shows that $|OD'|=yx$. Prove that $D'=D$ without using the fact that $xy=yx$ (i.e. without using any knowledge of the real numbers).

I'm really unsure of how do i show this. I thought of using Pappus' Theorem but when i drew the figure out, I can't seem to find an explicit proof.
Suppose $D\ne D'$, I aim to show the intersection of $A'C$ and $BB'$ with $CC'$ and $DB'$ is collinear with $CC'$ and $D'B'$.

But i don't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: Provide a figure, even hand-drawn, please.

Comment: @JeanMarie ok done

Comment: Your "not using the fact that xy=yx" reminds me strongly of the connexion of Pappus Theorem with the commutativity of the underneath field in nonstandard geometries. See for example p. 10 of the excellent paper "A Survey of the Development of Geometry up to 1870" by Eldar Straume http://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1140

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Pappus' Theorem is the way to go. The key point you're likely missing is $BB'\parallel CC'$. Combined with the green pairs being parallel, and the red lines being parallel, you have an Euclidean version of Pappus' Theorem, where some of the points of the configuration are actually points at infinity where the parallel lines intersect.

Comment: So basically because the points in the intersection with these 3 pairs of parallel lines for both the cases of $D$ and $D'$ line on the same line, the lines have to be the same. I think i can get that. but don't i have to explicitly prove it?

Comment: @Danxe: Depends on your background. I'm from a background of projective geometry. There one would have at some point proven that projective transformations preserve collinearities, and proven that parallel lines intersect at the line at infinity. Combining these, Pappus' Theorem with three points at infinity is equivalent with the generic finite version, so the proof of one would apply to the other. Depending on how you've proved Pappus' Theorem, that proof may or may not apply directly to this special case.

Comment: Another question is whether you can exchange assumption and conclusion in the theorem freely. For Pappus' Theorem this holds: if all incidences of the theorem except for one are given, then the last incidence holds and can be seen as the conclusion. This is true for all incidence theorems. So $C'D,B'D',BC$ are concurrent. Or $C'DD'$ are collinear, which amounts to the same thing. But whether you can simply choose to move the conclusion again depends on how you've proven Pappus' Theorem and whether you have this property for incidence theorems in general established.